# UWP: Hide ItemsControl items

Tags: win-universal-app, itemscontrol, windows-10-universal, listbox-control

I have an ItemsControl inside another ItemsControl. This ItemsControl, contains a list of sold items.

I would like to display those items that sold below the cost (negative profit).
But I am having problem collapsing the item (row).

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                ...
                ...
                ...
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SoldItems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>  <!--If I hide the grid, it will create empty space.-->
                                ...
                                ...
                                ...
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Profit}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If I tried to hide the grid, it displays empty row. It looks weird as it has empty gap there.

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Profit, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ProfitVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Any idea how to hide the entire row?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use Listbox instead of ItemsControl. I'm afraid with itemscontrol you dont have any option other than removing unwanted items. If you can use ListBox I can provide you solution

Comment: Yes yes, I can use a ListBox... Could you help me? :)

Comment: Actually you can do with the ItemsControl. I found other solution. Ok i ll post the answer.

Comment: Hey, Just wanted to check if anyone else has found any better approach than the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid Visibility="{Binding visible}"  Tag="{Binding ElementName=MyListView}" Loaded="Grid_Loaded"  >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```cs
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    // For items control
    // ContentPresenter item = (ContentPresenter)(grid.Tag as ItemsControl).ContainerFromItem(grid.DataContext);
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)(grid.Tag as ItemsControl).ContainerFromItem(grid.DataContext);
    // Or you can directly access listview
    // ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)(MyListView as ItemsControl).ContainerFromItem(grid.DataContext);
    if ((grid.DataContext as Test).visible == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding.Source = (grid.DataContext as your model class)
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("givevisibilityproperty");

            // Attach the binding to the target.
            item.SetBinding(ListViewItem.VisibilityProperty, binding);

            // (item ).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi LovetoCode, I tried your solution, but "grid.Tag" is null. any idea?

Comment: Hi Lovetocode, thanks for that! It works! However, when the field is updated (Profit becomes positive), it doesn't call Grid_Loaded again. Any idea?

Comment: It won't call. It ll be called only once when grid is loaded. You haven't mentioned this requirement in question, soo I gave you this solution

Comment: Thanks LovetoCode, I will mark this post as answer (until there are a better solution). Please post a solution if you do find one. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sam I edited the answer. Set binding to Listviewitem instead. So it ll be updated when visibility is changed. I hope it works. Not able to test now

Comment: Has anyone told you that you are a genius? It WORKED!!! Thanks mate, really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Would you be able to help me on this question? I have been tearing my hair out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209628/uwp-popup-maxwidth